# boto3 interaction with Amazon DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to add some information to my table in Amazon  DynamoDB using python script that i run on my ec2 instance and I have this error can any one help me solve the problem:

```html
>>> import boto3
>>> import json
>>> dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
>>> response = boto3.resource("dynamodb", region_name="eu-west-3")
>>> table = dynamodb.Table('Blocked_IP')
>>> response = table.put_item(
...     Item={
...     "RULEID": "154",
...     "NACLID": "acl-a54846c8",
...     "IP": "IP",
...     "TIME": "TIME"
...                 })
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(*args, **params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutItem operation: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key Blocked_IP in the item
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your DynamoDB table has a primary key attribute with the name `Blocked_IP`. Every record in the table has to have a value for that attribute. You have tried to add a record to the table without any value for that attribute.

It appears you are mistakenly setting an attribute named `IP` when you should be setting an attribute named `Blocked_IP`.

Your code needs to look something like this (replacing the hard-coded values with the actual values you want to insert):

```
response = table.put_item(
     Item={
     "RULEID": "154",
     "NACLID": "acl-a54846c8",
     "Blocked_IP": "IP",
     "TIME": "TIME"
})
```

Comment: @learn.amzn21 See the update to my answer

Comment: Yes, I have a primary key attribute with the name Blocked_IP. I just fixed the problem thanks.